# AZURE - Is it possible to restore from backup using ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

We create a vault and a VM to backup into it using an arm template. Now we want to restore this but can't find anything in the arm docs for restoring backups? Any thoughts if this is possible. We can script it other ways but want to see if we can keep it all arm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/restores/trigger#restore-to-new-azure-iaasvm) its not possible. ARM Templates can only do PUT requests, not POST.

this outlines the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-userestapi-restoreazurevms

Comment: Thanks, that's what we suspected. We are trying the Microsoft Resources/deploymentscripts to see if we can do it that way.